# Python Login-Post request to REST-API

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests

I'm setting up a workflow with a REST-Api and Python using the requests-package in a project.

I am new to the topic, but i was able to use the Restlet-plugin from Chrome to perform the login-step. However i am unable to do the same with Python using requests.

```
python
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'https://my-rest-url.net/api/v2/login'
body = {"username":"testuser", "password":"testpw"}

import certifi
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())

myResponse = requests.post(url, data=body, verify =True, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'my-rest-url.net'})
```

If i run myResponse i get `Response [400]` and would expect it to be `Response [200]`

I am getting  the following error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-rest-url.net', port=443):
>
> Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/login (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

Note: I have changed the host value and url value in the SSLError message.

Edit: Added PoolManager for certificates. Leads to same error.

Comment: Looks like python doesn't trust your server. Set `verify=False` in the parameters of `requests.post(...)` to check if it works in general.

Comment: Please stop suggesting ```verify=False``` without explaining implications of such option! Better get the server certificate and make the verification with ```verify='/path/to/server/certificate'```

Comment: I have added a Poolmanager, based on this link : [link](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl) and restartet the kernel, but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a iptables issue. Change https to http or edit your server iptables to allow all https traffic.